# Change formatting of address from carriage return style to comma separated format?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have customers who are placing orders and sending address in typical carriage-return format, e.g.

```
Foo Bar
100 Main St
Apt #4
New York
NY 
10001
```

I need the format to automatically convert to comma separated format:

**Foo Bar,100 Main St, Apt #4,New York, NY, 10002**

If the apartment/suite number is missing, it would just be blank between those 2 commas, e.g.

**Foo Bar, 100 Main St, , New York, NY, 10002**

The reason for comma separated is because it's being pasted into an excel CSV file. Is there a way to automatically transform the carriage-return format to comma separated? The amount of data is same (Name, Address, Apt/Suite, City, State, Zip.

This would be a tremendous help and I assume it requires VBA. Thanks!

The values need to be in a different column in Excel csv file. Each section (Name, Address, Suite/Apt, City, State, Zip).

**EDIT: Please let me know if any other info is needed.**

Comment: How is the data formatted in excel? Is there one address with newlines in each cell, or does each line get split to different cells? Is there any separator between one address and another?

Comment: No separator, since it's Excel saved as CSV. Basically each segment of the address would be in a different column. So one column for name, one for address, one for apt/suite, one for city, one for state and one for zip. If it's missing apt/suite we leave that one blank.

Comment: Got it. And do you want to directly manipulate the CSV or will you import it to excel first then export back to csv?

Comment: Correct, import it to excel and then export back to csv. THat would be perfect!

Comment: I'm willing to tip if you bitcoin address as well.

Comment: Any hints on the right direction are also appreciated! Each segment is in a different column on the same row. Each row represents one address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary workbook. scan down input data copying each line to corresponding column in new workbook. Then save as CSV and close temporary workbook.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateCSV()

   Const CSVNAME = "clients.csv"
   
   Dim wbCSV As Workbook, wsCSV As Worksheet, rCSV As Long
   Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
   Dim CSVfullname As String, ar
   
   ' temp workbook to save as CSV
   Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Add(1)
   Set wsCSV = wbCSV.Sheets(1)
   
   'scan addresses
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       
       r = 1
       Do While r <= lastrow
            If Len(.Cells(r, 1)) = 0 Then
                r = r + 1
            Else
                ' copy next 6 lines to csv sheet
                rCSV = rCSV + 1
                For c = 1 To 4
                    If c = 4 Then
                        ' split 4th line into 3 columns
                        ar = Split(.Cells(r, 1), ",")
                        For n = 0 To UBound(ar)
                            wsCSV.Cells(rCSV, c + n) = ar(n)
                        Next
                    Else
                        wsCSV.Cells(rCSV, c) = .Cells(r, 1)
                    End If
                    r = r + 1
                Next
          End If
       Loop
   End With
   
   ' save temp workbook
   CSVfullname = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & CSVNAME
   wbCSV.SaveAs CSVfullname, FileFormat:=xlCSV
   wbCSV.Close savechanges:=False
   
   ' result
   MsgBox rCSV & " records saved to " & CSVfullname, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anyway for this to account for address format where the City, State and Zip are on the same line. That's usually how addresses are sent to us. That would be super helpful and solve the problem entirely.

Comment: @helloworld Do all the address have the  city, state and zip on the last line or just some ? Are there commas between city and state, state and zip ?

Comment: All of them do, which makes it a bit easiser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's cleaner ways but this is a simple way. Copies the range of the address' (assuming there is one cell blank for apartment if it does not exist), then transposes it (note: cannot transpose on top of the copy area). Deletes the original copied address and splits the City, state and zip as needed.

```
Private Sub tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("test")
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A4")
    Dim pasted As Range
    Set pasted = ws.Range("B1")
    
    Dim parts() As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    rng.Copy
    ws.Range("B1:E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, _
    Transpose:=True
    rng.ClearContents
    
    temp = Replace(pasted.Offset(0, 3).Value, ",", "")
    parts = Split(temp, " ")
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(parts)
        pasted.Offset(0, i + 3) = parts(i)
    Next i
    
    If pasted.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then
        pasted.Offset(0, 2).Delete
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Edit: Rewrote code to work for scenario

Comment: Thank you! I will tip you if it works correctly. Do you have  BTC address? Let me test first. Thank you.

Comment: All good, just the rep is enough

Comment: Hmm, it's producing weird values. Thisi s what is produces: `Jason Yaraghi, , , 
191 Main St, , , 
Apt #4, , , 
Port Washington, NY 11050, , ,` It doesn't place each value in a new column within the same row, which is desired.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the excel sheet, or just one line of the original sheet?

Comment: No need for commas, excel will take care of that. I just need each value in a separate column on the same row, each address shares this format.

Comment: Sure here you go: https://imgur.com/a/I9cwGKK -- Ideally id paste the value in excel, run the function and it will take each segment and put it in a separate column but on the SAME ROW. So ideal results look like this: https://imgur.com/a/33Qqhc0 -- Thanks for the effort but its not matching up.

Comment: Are the other address' located underneath each one or in the next column? Also when there is no apartment no is there a blank cell or does it just skip?

Comment: I have rewritten the code for your described scenario

Comment: This is ignoring last 2 values, state and zip. It does everything else perfectly though!

Comment: Hm that’s odd, it worked for me. For the city/state/zip line I used as a test: City, State 10001. Is that not the same format as your data?